# PHP upload a file to a directory outside the webserver root

Tags: php, apache

So I have a question for you guys... I am trying to write a web site in PHP that will allow people to upload images to my server. I have the upload part working, so that's not the issue. The issue is when I try and write the uploaded files to a directory outside of apache's document root.

Apache's document root is /var/www/, and the directory I am trying to save these images to is /mnt/storage/images/. I have created the directory, changed the group to www-data, and changed the permissions on the directory to 777 (even though I know that's horrible security wise). I tried a few things with the apache configuration file, /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, namely adding a  tag and an Alias line, but nothing seems to work. Every time I try and upload a file to the images directory, it gives me a permission error. I've even tried putting a few files there manually and navigating to the directory, using the alias, with the web browser, and I get a 403 error.

I know I am either doing something wrong, or I haven't done something to make this work. I have googled around for help on this for a few days now, and all I find is useless information, or bits and pieces of information that barely help at all.

Btw... I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 using Apache 2.2.17, and I have root access and all that jazz.

Thanks,
Robbie

EDIT: Here is the part of the apache config that I put in:

```
Alias /images "/mnt/storage/images/"
<Directory "/mnt/storage/images/">
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: could you post the relevant parts of your apache config? Might want to fix the 403 error first.

Comment: check apache rights on directories /mnt/storage/ and /mnt it should at least get the x right on all these directories (some if the apache user and group is not on user or group of these directory it means it should be on the third-all right).

Comment: If you don't mind, can you paste the piece of code that writes to a different directory + enable XDEBUG and trace the flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to grant Apache access permissions on ALL of the directories involved:

```
/mnt
/mnt/storage
/mnt/storage/images
```

There's no point in doing 777 on `images` if Apache has no rights on the `storage` or `mnt` directories.

Of course, only `images` would need to have write permissions, as that's where you're actually doing file operations. `mnt` and `storage` would need at most read permissions, and you can get away from doing global (xx7) permissions by putting Apache's user account into a group and chgrp the images directory to that new group.

Comment: OMG Thank you! I didn't realize I had to give read/write permissions to the apache user. I can't believe that something so simple slipped past me. I guess it happens :P

Answer (score 0):

You probably have `safe_mode` enabled in PHP. Turn it off.

Comment: I checked for that and, no, I don't have it turned on

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the `open_basedir`. You can turn this on and off for specific domains...
Try something along the lines of

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs>
        php_admin_flag engine on
        php_admin_value open_basedir none
</Directory>
```

(Info here)[http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=62750%22] if you are using Plesk. Or you should hopefully be able to conform it to what ever you are using