# Save files with storeAs outside the Storage folder

Tags: laravel-5.5

I have in an API in Laravel that stores files

```
$request->file("file$i")->storeAs('categories', $nameFile)
```

As it stands it stores the data correctly in the address

```
/var/www/html/apiapp/storage/app/public/categories
```

But I would like to save these files in the folder

```
/var/archives
```

Because these files will be accessed by another application

Comment: I think you just need to give the write permission to that folder for www-data user

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The third argument of `storeAs` tells on which storage disk the file should be saved

```
$path = $request->photo->storeAs('images', 'filename.jpg', 's3');
```

So, create a new *disk* in `config/filesystem.php` and point it to `/var/archives`

```
'disks' => [

    // ...

    'archive' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => '/var/archives',
    ],

    // ...
```

In the code:

```
$request->file("file$i")->storeAs('categories', $nameFile, 'archive')
```

Ensure that the user running the webserver has permission to save to that folder on disk as well.

Another alternative is to share an external storage, such as AWS S3 for example. The configuration for this follows the same idea.

I received this [answer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266990/salvar-arquivos-com-storeas-fora-da-pasta-storage/267011#267011) on stackoverflow in Portuguese and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

To save your files to a directory outside the webserver root directory `/var/www/html` You should configure your webserver. Similar problems:

[PHP upload a file to a directory outside the webserver root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325107/php-upload-a-file-to-a-directory-outside-the-webserver-root)
[Set Apache to allow access for a directory not under document root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240614/set-apache-to-allow-access-for-a-directory-not-under-document-root)

You can read this, too:
[Mapping URLs to Filesystem Locations](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html)